# how to select only cell A1,A3,A5,A7....till end of the row in excel using formual

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please help I want to know *how to select a cell* which is shown in **screen shoot** in excel using formula

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Why are you selecting them?

Comment: i want to sum that cells values

Comment: and i have thousands of values

Comment: `mod` is the key here.

Comment: i can't undestand

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an array formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shft</kbd> <kbd>Entr</kbd> after typing it. You should see curly brackets appear around it.

This starts with the second cell -

```
=SUM(A:A*(MOD(ROW(A:A),2)=0))
```

This starts with the first cell -

```
=SUM(A:A*((MOD(ROW(A:A),2)-1)=0))
```

Comment: its shows wrong answer

Comment: you may change the second formula to `=SUM(A:A*(MOD(ROW(A:A),x)=y))` while x isthe distance between the cells and y the first cell to start with, if x = y then y = 0 (y cant be bigger then x)... so for your example `=SUM(A:A*(MOD(ROW(A:A),2)=1))` may be better :)

Comment: @DirkReichel yeah, that's true.